# IIS web site not accessible from the hosted server

Tags: iis-8

I hosted a website in IIS 8 and binding with a proper hosting name (subdomain.xyz.com). It is working from my local machine, but it is not working when I access from hosted server. It is showing authentication window, even I provide a valid credentials it is showing again and again.

The server is hosted in Azure. 
Server: Windows Server 2012 R2

Comment: "it is not working", ahm..  what do you mean by "not working"? the port is not responding when you run a port-scan? is the port responding, but you're not getting a website? when you run netstat on the server, is IIS really listening on port 80? are you behind a firewall?

Comment: When am trying to access outside the firewall it is working fine. In the same machine (hosted) it is not working.

Answer (score 1):

It is because NAT loopback,
you can try to use internal ip if you access from hosted server.
if you want to access using your hosting name, make sure to point it inside "hosts" file.

> C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts

add this line

> 127.0.0.1     subdomain.xyz.com

so basically what hosts file do is, it actually point to your localhost every time you enter subdomain.xyz.com in your browser.